# Azure Databricks: How do we access R Scripts present on DBFS?

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm new to DataBricks. I am trying to access a .R file that is present in the DBFS storage but I cannot figure out how to do so. Any help is really appreciated.
I can read data from the storage using the file path /dbfs and also source code from the script but I want to make edits to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need some editor to do that - for example, you can [setup RStudio on your cluster and connect to it via RStudio UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/sparkr/rstudio) - in this case you can edit R files directly on DBFS.

But really, the simplest for you would be to use [Databricks CLI fs command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/dbfs-cli) to copy the file to your local machine, make changes in the editor of your choice, and upload file back.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that Alex. I did set up RStudio on a cluster but, I am unable to see any files on the DBFS in the RStudio UI. Do you think there is some setting that needs to be changed to see the files on DBFS in the RStudio environment?

Comment: Have you tried to look for path starting with /dbfs/…

Comment: I get a status code of 504 when I try to search for that path in RStudio.

Comment: Hmm, maybe something wrong in the setup. Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/sparkr/rstudio#how-should-i-persist-my-work-on-rstudio) says: "You can also save your files (code or data) on the Databricks File System (DBFS). For example, if you save a file under /dbfs/ the files will not be deleted when your cluster is terminated or restarted."